# ¿Cómo alineo y centro unos divs y hago el color de fondo llegue hasta abajo?

Tags: html, css

Necesito que estas 3 cajas queden como en la imagen que adjunto: centradas horizontalmente, a la misma altura todas (ahora cada una baja un pelín más que la anterior), y que el fondo azul llegue hasta abajo.

Para que estas cajas aparezcan, hay que sobrevolar el `div` del título

[image: resultado final]

Snippet a continuación: ver en pantalla completa.

```css
.seguros{
   background-color: deepskyblue;
    font-family: "Barrio";
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 2% 0% 2% 4%;
}

.oculta {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.52em;
  padding: 0.3% 0% 0% 0%; 
}

.seguros:hover .oculta {
    display: block;    
    color: #2c2b2b;
    font-family: "Questrial";
}

.ficha {
    border: 2px solid #2c2b2b;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 1%;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.promo {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}

.expire {
    color: deeppink;
}

#link{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="seguros.html">    
    <div class="seguros">
      <p> >>>> Seguros & Hipotecas <<<<  </p>

                <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha">  
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel </span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                 <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha"> 
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel</span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                 <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha">   
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel </span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para extender el fondo usamos `overflow:auto` para centrar `text-align:center` para que las cajas se comporten como si fueran letras y asi tomar el `text-align` del padre, usamos `display:inline-block`

```css
.seguros{
   background-color: deepskyblue;
    font-family: "Barrio";
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding: 2% 0% 2% 4%;
    overflow:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.oculta {
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.52em;
  padding: 0.3% 0% 0% 0%; 
  max-width: 320px;
}

.seguros:hover .oculta {
    display: inline-block;    
    color: #2c2b2b;
    font-family: "Questrial";
}

.ficha {
    border: 2px solid #2c2b2b;
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 1%;
    max-width: 450px;
    min-width: 300px;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.promo {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}

.expire {
    color: deeppink;
}

#link{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="seguros.html">    
    <div class="seguros">
      <p> >>>> Seguros & Hipotecas <<<<  </p>

                <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha">  
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel </span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                 <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha"> 
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel</span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                 <div class="oculta">   
                     <div class="ficha">   
                          <div class="container">
                            <h4>Seguro baja autónomo</h4>
                          </div>
                          <img src="autonomo.jpg" alt="seguro autonomo" style="width:100%;">
                          <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
                            <h2><b>desde sólo 25€/mes</b></h2> 
                            <p>Cobras la baja entera según baremo, al 5ª día de presentarnos la baja</p>
                            <p>Sin visitas médicas</p>
                            <p>Incluye un seguro de vida</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <p>Más información <span class="promo">tel </span></p>
                            <p class="expire">Expires: Jan 03, 2017</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: hola, lo de  overflow:auto; ha funcionado, pero al centrar quedan dos cajas en una linea muy separadas y 3a. caja se va abajo

Comment: no veo los cambios, sigue haciendo lo mismo

Comment: ahi te agregué un `max-width` al contenedor de las fichas, sin eso va a tratar de ocupar todo el espacio al que lo fuerza el hijo `ficha` con su `width` y `max-width`

Comment: el display: inline-block;  tiene que ser none y el max-width hace que vaya una caja debajo de la otra y no al lado, ejecuta tu codigo y lo veras